# Delete single record Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm fairly new to Laravel and would like to create a functionality where I will delete a single record from the database by clicking a link.

Below is the code on the view:

```
@foreach($companies as $company)
     <tr>
         <td><a href="/companies/{{$company->id}}"> {{$company->name}}</a></td>
         <td><a href="/companies/{{$company->id}}"> {{$company->descriptions}}</a></td>
         <td><a href="/companies/{{$company->id}}"> {{$company->comptype->name}}</a></td>
         <td>

              <a href="{{route('companies.edit', $company->id)}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>

               <a onclick="
                     var result = confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this Company?');
       if( result ){ 
    event.preventDefault();
                                                                      document.getElementById('delete-form').submit();
                       }
                                                                  "
                                                   class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </a>

                 <form id="delete-form" action="{{ route('companies.destroy',[$company->id]) }}"
                                                      method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
                                                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                 </form>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
@endforeach
```

Next is the destroy method in the Controller

```
public function destroy(Company $company)
{
    //
   // dd($company);
    $findCompany = Company::findOrFail( $company->id);


    if($findCompany->delete()){

        //redirect
        return redirect()->route('companies.index')
            ->with('success' , 'Company deleted successfully');
    }

    return back()->withInput()->with('error' , 'Company could not be deleted');
}
```

The form looks like this:
[image]

When clicking on trash, to delete a particular record, the record on the table gets deleted and it doesn't matter which I try to delete, the first record always gets deleted.  When I did a diedown, I found that the URL has the correct record but dd shows that the first record will be deleted.  I am fairly new to Laravel, I've done this using Laravelcollective/html, but unfortunately it's not compatible with Laravel 5.5.28.  Please be so kind to assist

Comment: did you print $company->id in your controller ? you got it correct every time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in JS code. Your JS code always sumbits the same delete form. To fix this, you need to use unique IDs:

```
<form id="delete-form{{ $company->id }}"
```

And then:

```
document.getElementById('delete-form{{ $company->id }}').submit();
```

Also, mixing JS and PHP is a bad practice. You should really put all the JS into a separate JS file.

Answer (score 1):

Try That way it's my project code :

View File :

```
<td>
<form action="{{action('TagController@destroy', $row['id'])}}" method="post">
{{csrf_field()}}
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
</td>
```

TagController.php:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {   


        $tags = Tag::find($id);
         $success = $tags->delete();

            if($success)
            {
                return redirect('/admin/tag')
                ->with('success','Tag deleted.');
            }

        return back()->withInput()->with('errors','Some error...');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
see the form action `"{{ route('companies.destroy',[$company->id]) }}"` to `{{ url('companies/destroy/'.$company->id) }}`
   see the destroy methos in wrong 
   Click the [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers)

Perfect Method

```
public function destroy($id){
$findCompany = Company::findOrFail($id);
if($findCompany->delete()){
    //redirect
    return redirect()->route('companies.index')
        ->with('success' , 'Company deleted successfully');
}
return back()->withInput()->with('error' , 'Company could not be deleted');}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for view file :

```
 <div class="col-xs-12">
<a href="{{url('/delete')}}/{{$allDemos[$i]->id}}"  class='btndelete'>
     <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</a>
```

SliderControler.php :

```
 public function delete($id){
      $Slider = Slider::find($id); 
      unlink('slider_images/'.$Slider->slider_img);   
      $Slider->delete();
      return redirect('/slider');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function destroy(Company $company)
{ 
    if($company->delete()){
        //redirect
        return redirect()->route('companies.index')
            ->with('success' , 'Company deleted successfully');
    }

    return back()->withInput()->with('error' , 'Company could not be deleted');
}
```